# How to restore partitions and data after diskpart "clean" command?

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

I was on my way installing windows 7 alongside linux installation that was scattered over 3 partitions, namely: root, home and additional big partition for data files. I was trying to install windows on 4th a non mbr empty partition that was specifically created for windows. When I booted from windows 7 DVD, I used "shift+F10" command to enter a command line interface and used "diskpart" app. While going through the disk partitions and selecting the empty volume I typed "clean" thinking that it would erase ONLY the selected volume, but instead the whole hdd drive was removed of its partitions. I could barely stand because the information on those non empty linux partitions is irreplaceable and worth months of work.

What should I do to get my data back guys?
I have 2 usb sticks, 2 external hdds, another windows laptop and internet connection.

Comment: TestDisk, R-Studio, GetDataBack... No end to the number of data recovery tools (many of which can also work with disk images), most of which have been suggested multiple times in previous questions. Do NOT attempt to recover to the same drive, and don't use the drive for anything else until recovery is complete.

Comment: I would try the partition wizard recovery tool ==> http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to restore partition layout but I was able to restore all the data with R-Studio and save it on external hdd. R-Studio appeared to be a very nice app for this task.